# Checkout redirects to checkout again after purchase - no order created

Tags: magento2, checkout, redirect

**Magento 2.2.3**

Whenever I buy something in my store, I am being redirected to the checkout again, just as if I did not press the "buy now" button. The cart is still filled, no order is created. I checked the logs and found nothing suspicous.

**Its the Magento 2 standard checkout. Any idweas where to start looking?**

> Thanks!

Comment: Can u please check mail related configuration?. Sometimes this problem happened because of incorrect configuration.

Comment: Any hint on what to look for? Seems to be ok I would say.